# Type-checking acting weird in monorepo

Tags: typescript, types, tsconfig, monorepo, typechecking

So I'm running a monorepo with Turborepo, with an Electron app and a NextJS website in it. It's built ontop the [`create-t3-turbo`](https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-turbo) template.

Here is my folder structure:

```
apps
  ├─ client
  |   ├─ src
  |   |   ├─ main
  |   |   |   └─ [...]
  |   |   ├─ preload
  |   |   |   └─ [...]
  |   |   └─ renderer
  |   |       └─ [...]
  |   ├─ tsconfig.node.json
  |   ├─ tsconfig.web.json
  |   └─ tsconfig.json
  └─ website
      └─ [...]

packages
 ├─ api
 |   └─ [...]
 ├─ auth
 |   └─ [...]
 ├─ db
 |   └─ [...]
 ├─ eslint
 |   └─ [...]
 └─ tailwind
     └─ [...]

tsconfig.json
```

The problem is with the `typecheck` npm script. Here are my files:

```json
// tsconfig.json in the repo's root dir
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "lib": [ "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext" ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
    }
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json in apps/client
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "files": [],
    "exclude": [],
    "references": [
        { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" },
        { "path": "./tsconfig.web.json" }
    ]
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.node.json in apps/client
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "extends": "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true
    },
    "include": [ "electron.vite.config.ts", "src/main", "src/preload" ],
    "exclude": []
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.web.json in apps/client
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "extends": "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [ "src/renderer/src/*" ]
        }
    },
    "include": [ "src/renderer/src", "src/preload/window.d.ts", "src/renderer/vite-env.d.ts" ],
    "exclude": []
}
```

```json
// package.json in apps/client
{
    "name": "@monorepo/client",
    "main": "./out/main/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "typecheck:node": "tsc -p tsconfig.node.json --noEmit --composite false",
        "typecheck:web": "tsc -p tsconfig.web.json --noEmit --composite false",
        "typecheck": "pnpm typecheck:node && pnpm typecheck:web"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@electron-toolkit/preload": "^1.0.2",
        "@electron-toolkit/utils": "^1.0.2",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig": "^1.0.1",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.16.1",
        "@trpc/client": "10.1.0",
        "@trpc/react-query": "10.1.0",
        "@trpc/server": "10.1.0",
        "@monorepo/api": "*",
        "@monorepo/eslint": "*",
        "@monorepo/tailwind": "*",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3",
        "vite": "^3.2.4",
        "[...]": ""
    }
}
```

Just having `@monorepo/api` as a dependency for `apps/client` is fine, no problems there. But as soon as I import anything from `monorepo/api` in `apps/client`, I get the following errors:

```
Found 58 errors in 7 files.

Errors  Files
     1  src/main/utils/trpc.ts:6
    14  ../../packages/api/src/routes/blockUser.ts:11
    24  ../../packages/api/src/routes/friends.ts:52
     3  ../../packages/api/src/routes/sessions.ts:26
     4  ../../packages/api/src/routes/users.ts:11
     2  ../../packages/api/src/trpc.ts:16
    10  ../../packages/auth/src/auth-options.ts:23
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If I run `tsc --noEmit` in `packages/api`, everything runs fine, I don't get any type errors. Weirdly enough, if I run the same command in `apps/website` which is a NextJS app also using `@monorepo/api`, I get no errors.